# Restkit mapping of array of heterogeneous arrays

Tags: mapping, restkit

I am totally stuck trying to map this JSON data:

```
{
  "All_Data": [
    {
      "TANTENNE": [
        {"ID": 2068, "KIND": "PARABOLE"}, 
        {"ID": 2069, "KIND": "ANTENNE TNT HERTZIENNE"}, 
        {"ID": 2070, "KIND": "ANTENNE COLLECTIVE"}, 
        {"ID": 2071, "KIND": "PARABOLE PLATE"}
      ],
      "totalCount": 4, 
      "success": true
    },
    {
      "success": true,
      "FANTENNE": [
        {"ID": 1121, "CONNECT": "Autre"}, 
        {"ID": 1122, "CONNECT": "Neovia"}, 
        {"ID": 1124, "CONNECT": "non"}, 
        {"ID": 1125, "CONNECT": "oui"}, 
        {"ID": 1126, "CONNECT": "Patch"}, 
        {"ID": 1127, "CONNECT": "SRTD"}, 
        {"ID": 1128, "CONNECT": "Standard"}
      ],
      "totalCount": 7
    },
    {
      "MANTENNE": [
        {"ID": 2065, "STATUS": "NON PRESENTE", "ACTION": 1}, 
        {"ID": 2066, "STATUS": "DEFECTUEUSE", "ACTION": 2}, 
        {"ID": 2067, "STATUS": "2EME ANTENNE POSEE", "ACTION": 3}
      ],
      "totalCount": 3, 
      "success": true
    }, 
    {
      "totalCount": 5, 
      "LANTENNE": [
        {"ID": 1139, "LOCATION": "AU SOL"}, 
        {"ID": 1140, "LOCATION": "Balcon"}, 
        {"ID": 1142, "LOCATION": "FACADE"}, 
        {"ID": 1143, "LOCATION": "Toit"}, 
        {"ID": 2064, "LOCATION": "JARDIN"}
      ], 
      "success": true
    }, 
  ], 
  "success": true
}
```

Given that I have Core Data entities (and associated classes for all individual leaf objects (`TANTENNE`, `FANTENNE`, `MANTENNE`, `LANTENNE`).

When I receive the above JSON, I would like to insert 4 instances of `TANTENNE`, 7 instances of `FANTENNE`, 3 instances of `MANTENNE`, and 5 instances `LANTENNE`.

I have individual mappings for those classes, e.g.:

```
RKManagedObjectMapping *mapping =  [RKManagedObjectMapping mappingForEntityWithName:@"TANTENNE" inManagedObjectStore:self.objectStore];
mapping.primaryKeyAttribute = @"id";

[mapping mapKeyPathsToAttributes:
 @"ID", @"id",
 @"KIND", @"kind",
 nil];

[self setObjectMapping:mapping forKeyPath:@"TANTENNE"];
```

This is called at initialization time of my mapping provider. But this is clearly not enough as I get console messages such as

```
[…] T restkit.object_mapping:RKObjectMapper.m:293 Examining keyPath 'TANTENNE' for mappable content...
[…] D restkit.object_mapping:RKObjectMapper.m:303 Found unmappable value at keyPath: TANTENNE
```

If I add the mapping using the "All_Combo.TANTENNE" key path, then RestKit crashes later trying to map a full array to one destination object.

This is with RestKit 0.10 (I haven't moved to 0.20 because all the Magical Record stuff is gone, and I use it a lot).

Thanks for any insight.

Comment: Any progress on this? I'm running into the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

I've got to things in mind that will perhaps break your mapping.

1) Root Key Path
Configure the root key path via `mapping.rootKeyPath = @"All_Data"`vor each mapping to ensure that the mapping for the key path "TANTENNE" wouldn't expect that value in the root of your returned JSON.

2) Dictionary inside Array
Because of the fact that these values of "TANTENNE" are send in a dictionary if may be a requirement to use an additional confiugration. Connecting the root of the "TANTENNE" array to the values inside the dictionary by using `[mapping mapRelationship:@"TANTENNE" withMapping:mapping];` - perhaps it works.